# apache-cxf client works with exec-maven-plugin, but not from outside

Tags: cxf, webservices-client, exec-maven-plugin

I am having problems triying to create a WS client in java.

The libraries I'm using is **apache-cxf 2.12**. This is an old version but I want the web service to be added to a JBoss application that is already running and uses Spring 2.5.6, so this **org.apache.cxf** version uses same spring  version.

But the question is (I know is quite generic, is related to maven, netbeans and apache-cxf)

When I execute my client project (maven proyect) from netbeans, it works sort of Ok. 
When I try to  run this class with a script (bot windows an linux) it  gives me this error:

**"Invocation failed with the following: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied."**

Java versions are the same, I've copied all the dependency jar into lib dir and added then to %classpath%

So, what can be different that when I execute my sample program with maven **org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec** it works and it doesn't when I run it with a srcipt? (I have checked all dependencies, java version, ... )

I guess it has to be related to JAX-WS o JCE (Java Cryptography Architecture) initialization.

¿Is there a way to see what %classpath  maven is creating when in runs java.exe?

Maven script that works:

```
JAVA_HOME=D:\\LOCAL\\Java\\jdk1.5.0_15 
D:\\LOCAL\\apache-maven-2.0.9\\bin\\mvn.bat 
-Dexec.classpathScope=runtime 
-DskipTests=true 
"-Dexec.args=-Djavax.net.debug=all -classpath %classpath es.webservice.aaTest TESTFILE" 
-Dexec.executable=D:\\LOCAL\\Java\\jdk1.5.0_15\\bin\\java.exe 
-Dmaven.repo.local=D:\\bsrepo\\.m2 process-classes 
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec
```

Thanks